# Detector de barras en python con anaconda

Tags: python, tkinter

Estoy creando un detector de barras en Python con Anaconda, pero me sale este error:

```
Error Imagen
No imagen
```

No puedo mostrar mi frame. ¿Alguien me puede ayudar?

Aqui el código:

```
import Tkinter
import cv
from Tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import sys
from time import *

image_path = None
try:
    image_path = sys.argv[1]
except:
    print "Error Imagen"

class App:
    def __init__(self, master, image_path):
        self.nombre_imagen = image_path
        self.imagen_original = self.abrir_original()
        self.imagen_actual = self.imagen_original
        self.x, self.y = self.imagen_original.size
        self.master = master
        self.frame = Frame(self.master)
        self.frame.pack()
#-------------------------- botones
        self.procesar = Button(self.frame, text = "Ubicar Codigo", fg = "red", command = self.procesar)
        self.guarda = Button(self.frame, text = "Guardar Imagen", fg = "red", command = self.guardar)

        self.procesar.grid(row=0, column = 0, padx = 10, pady = 10)
        self.guarda.grid(row=0, column = 1, padx =10, pady = 10)
        foto = Image.open(image_path)
        foto = ImageTk.PhotoImage(foto)
        self.picture = Label(self.frame, image = foto)
        self.picture.image = foto
        self.picture.grid(row=1, column = 0, columnspan = 7, sticky= W+E+N+S, padx=5, pady=5)
#----------------------------abrir
    def abrir_original(self):
        imagen = Image.open(self.nombre_imagen)
        imagen = imagen.convert('RGB')
        return imagen

    def guardar(self, imgco):
        cv.SaveImage("codigo.jpg",imgco)
        self.imagen_actual.save('detectado.jpg')

    def actualizar_imagen(self):
        foto = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.imagen_actual)
        self.picture = Label(self.frame, image = foto)
        self.picture.image = foto
        self.picture.grid(row =1,column = 0, columnspan=7,sticky=W+E+N+S, padx=5, pady=5)

    def procesar(self):
        time1 = time()
        global image_path
        imgco = cv.LoadImage(image_path) #cargar imagen
        img = cv.CreateImage(cv.GetSize(imgco),8,1)
        imgx = cv.CreateImage(cv.GetSize(img),cv.IPL_DEPTH_16S,1)
        imgy = cv.CreateImage(cv.GetSize(img),cv.IPL_DEPTH_16S,1)
        thresh = cv.CreateImage(cv.GetSize(img),8,1)
#------------Proceso
        #----------Escala de grises
        cv.CvtColor(imgco,img,cv.CV_BGR2GRAY)
        cv.SaveImage("eg.jpg",imgco)

        #----------Aplicamos gradientes ---Mascara de Sobel
        cv.Sobel(img,imgx,1,0,3)
        cv.Abs(imgx,imgx)

        cv.Sobel(img,imgy,0,1,3)
        cv.Abs(imgy,imgy)

        cv.Sub(imgx,imgy,imgx)
        cv.ConvertScale(imgx,img)

        #----------Filtro
        cv.Smooth(img,img,cv.CV_GAUSSIAN,7,7,0)

        #----------Aplicacion de Umbrales
        cv.Threshold(img,thresh,100,255,cv.CV_THRESH_BINARY)

        cv.Erode(thresh,thresh,None,2)
        cv.Dilate(thresh,thresh,None,5)

        storage = cv.CreateMemStorage(0)
        contour = cv.FindContours(thresh, storage, cv.CV_RETR_CCOMP, cv.CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
        area = 0
        while contour:
            max_area = cv.ContourArea(contour)
            if max_area>area:
                area = max_area
                bar = list(contour) 
            contour=contour.h_next()

        bound_rect = cv.BoundingRect(bar)
        pt1 = (bound_rect[0], bound_rect[1])
        pt2 = (bound_rect[0] + bound_rect[2], bound_rect[1] + bound_rect[3])

        cv.Rectangle(imgco, pt1, pt2, cv.CV_RGB(255,0,255), 2)

        cv.ShowImage('img',imgco)    
        cv.WaitKey(0)
        time2 = time()
        timef = time2 - time1
        print "Tiempo de ejecucion: " +str(timef)+"segundos."
        return imgco
#--------------------------------Main
def main():
    try:
        image_path = sys.argv[1]
        print image_path
    except:
        print "No imagen"
        return
    root = Tk()
    proceso = App(root, image_path)
    root.title("Proceso de Imagen")
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__" :
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por el código que tienes pareces tener la intencion de que el script sea lanzado desde la línea de comandos pasandole como argumento la ruta de la imagen. El script debe ser llamado desde la terminal/cmd, por ejemplo, para abrir una imagen con la ruta 'C:/Imagenes/imagen.jpg' debes lanzar el script desde la terminal (a modo de ejemplo):

```
python myscript.py C:/Imagenes/imagen.jpg
```

Para ello hay que modificar algo tu programa, por ejemplo intentas capturar el argumento (ruta de la imagen) dos veces, una en la función `main` y otra al principio del script.

En `procesar` usas `global` para la ruta de la imagen. No es necesario ni debes usar variables globales, más aún en POO, usa el atributo correspondiente (`self.nombre_imagen`).

Por otro lado, debes evitar los imports redundantes y usar `from modulo import *`, es una mala práctica y ha de evitarse siempre. El código quedaría:

```
import sys
from time import time
import cv2 as cv
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import Tkinter as tk



class App:
    def __init__(self, master, image_path):
        self.nombre_imagen = image_path
        self.imagen_original = self.abrir_original()
        self.imagen_actual = self.imagen_original
        self.x, self.y = self.imagen_original.size
        self.master = master
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.master)
        self.frame.pack()
#-------------------------- botones
        self.procesar = tk.Button(self.frame, text = "Ubicar Codigo", fg = "red", command = self.procesar)
        self.guarda = tk.Button(self.frame, text = "Guardar Imagen", fg = "red", command = self.guardar)

        self.procesar.grid(row=0, column = 0, padx = 10, pady = 10)
        self.guarda.grid(row=0, column = 1, padx =10, pady = 10)
        foto = Image.open(image_path)
        foto = ImageTk.PhotoImage(foto)
        self.picture = tk.Label(self.frame, image = foto)
        self.picture.image = foto
        self.picture.grid(row=1, column = 0, columnspan = 7, sticky= 'wens', padx=5, pady=5)
#----------------------------abrir

    def abrir_original(self):
        imagen = Image.open(self.nombre_imagen)
        imagen = imagen.convert('RGB')
        return imagen

    def guardar(self, imgco):
        cv.SaveImage("codigo.jpg", imgco)
        self.imagen_actual.save('detectado.jpg')

    def actualizar_imagen(self):
        foto = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.imagen_actual)
        self.picture = tk.Label(self.frame, image = foto)
        self.picture.image = foto
        self.picture.grid(row =1,column = 0, columnspan=7,sticky='wens', padx=5, pady=5)

    def procesar(self):
        time1 = time()
        imgco = cv.LoadImage(self.nombre_imagen) #cargar imagen
        img = cv.CreateImage(cv.GetSize(imgco),8,1)
        imgx = cv.CreateImage(cv.GetSize(img),cv.IPL_DEPTH_16S,1)
        imgy = cv.CreateImage(cv.GetSize(img),cv.IPL_DEPTH_16S,1)
        thresh = cv.CreateImage(cv.GetSize(img),8,1)
#------------Proceso
        #----------Escala de grises
        cv.CvtColor(imgco,img,cv.CV_BGR2GRAY)
        cv.SaveImage("eg.jpg",imgco)

        #----------Aplicamos gradientes ---Mascara de Sobel
        cv.Sobel(img,imgx,1,0,3)
        cv.Abs(imgx,imgx)

        cv.Sobel(img,imgy,0,1,3)
        cv.Abs(imgy,imgy)

        cv.Sub(imgx,imgy,imgx)
        cv.ConvertScale(imgx,img)

        #----------Filtro
        cv.Smooth(img,img,cv.CV_GAUSSIAN,7,7,0)

        #----------Aplicacion de Umbrales
        cv.Threshold(img,thresh,100,255,cv.CV_THRESH_BINARY)

        cv.Erode(thresh,thresh,None,2)
        cv.Dilate(thresh,thresh,None,5)

        storage = cv.CreateMemStorage(0)
        contour = cv.FindContours(thresh, storage, cv.CV_RETR_CCOMP, cv.CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
        area = 0
        while contour:
            max_area = cv.ContourArea(contour)
            if max_area>area:
                area = max_area
                bar = list(contour) 
            contour=contour.h_next()

        bound_rect = cv.BoundingRect(bar)
        pt1 = (bound_rect[0], bound_rect[1])
        pt2 = (bound_rect[0] + bound_rect[2], bound_rect[1] + bound_rect[3])

        cv.Rectangle(imgco, pt1, pt2, cv.CV_RGB(255,0,255), 2)

        cv.ShowImage('img',imgco)    
        cv.WaitKey(0)
        timef = time() - time1
        print "Tiempo de ejecucion: {} segundos.".format(timef)
        return imgco
#--------------------------------Main
def main(image_path):

        root = tk.Tk()
        proceso = App(root, image_path)
        root.title("Proceso de Imagen")
        root.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__" :
    try:
        image_path = sys.argv[1]
        #image_path = 'XYZ.jpg'
        main(image_path)
    except IndexError as error:
        print "Error: No image path argument"
        print "Usage: myprogram.py <image_path>"
        sys.exit(1)
```

Como digo la idea es pasar la imagen como argumento al ejecutar el módulo en la terminal/CMD. Si quieres otra cosa (abrir la imagen desde la interfaz por ejemplo) deberias explicarlo para poder ayudarte.

Por otro lado, si esperas que `procesar` tarde un tiempo en terminar de ejecutarse deberás impelementarla usando hilos o procesos. De no hacerlo, la GUI se bloqueará mientras tanto.

Un ejemplo de uso en Windows:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Man quiero trabajar este proyecto contigo, contactame : ladino.92@hotmail.com

Comment: Hay manera de trabajar con Anaconda?